# Problem finding the maximum of a function in the first quadrant

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, maxima-minima

let $f(x,y) = xy - x^{3}y - xy^{3}$

I find that a LOCAL maximum is $(1/2,1/2)$

How do I know that point is the global maximum or the boundary of domain or $\infty $ is the global maximum?
In the first quadrant

Comment: Note that $f(x,y) = xy(1-x^2-y^2)$, so in the first quadrant, $f$ is non positive outside the unit disk. In particular, $f$ has a $\max$ in the positive quadrant.

Comment: What about the boundary of the domain? What value does $f$ have on the boundary???

Comment: @copper.hat can you elaborate more on your answer are you taking the limit as x,y goes to infinity?

Comment: $f$ is zero on the boundary (the axes), and $f(x,y) \le 0$ for $x^2+y^2 \ge 1$ (in the first quadrant). Since $f$ is strictly positive somewhere in the intersection of the quadrant and the closed unit disk (which is compact), $f$ must have a $\max$ there and it must be in the interior of this region, hence an unconstrained local $\max$. Since you have found the only local $\max$ it must be **the** solution.

Comment: @copper.hat thank you